# Wicket 6: Nested object's property without IModel hustle

Tags: model, wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

I have nested models like:

```
class User {
  private String name;
  private Address address;
  ...
}

class Address {
  private String city;
  ...
}
```

now, in Wicket 6, can I have a singe IModel to access all nested properties like:

```
IModel<User> userModel = new PropertyModel<>(user);
Form<User> form = new CSRFSafeForm<>("form", user);
form.add(new TextField<>("name"));
form.add(new TextField<>("address.city"));
```

Is it possible without any additional coding?

I've read Wicket's manual https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models but it says I need to create a new form and IModel.

Is it possible to edit both name and city on the same form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where CSRFSafeForm is coming from.

But you can do the same with a standard Form and CompoundPropertyModel:

```
IModel<User> userModel = new PropertyModel<>(user);
Form<User> form = new Form<>("form", new CompoundPropertyModel<User>(user));
form.add(new TextField<>("name"));
form.add(new TextField<>("address.city"));
```

Comment: you can remove 'userModel' (the first row) in your code to avoid some confusions.